# FrameLayout and percentage of screen

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, percentage, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout that above it shows a LinearLayout
My intention is that this LinearLayout always get up to 33% of the screen ... But I can not do it.
I tried using "dp" but of course, the result is different according to densities.
If they were two LinearLayout, if I could do using layout_weight = ".33" and layout_weight = ".67"
But FrameLayout use in one of them.

I hope to explain it properly

[image]

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yout can try something like this.
In first layer is ImageView and in second layer there are two linear layouts.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layoit_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layoit_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:image="@drawable/screen_image"/> //blue image whith white "screen"

    <LinearLayout
        android:layoit_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layoit_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".67"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layoit_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#44FF0000"> //33% layout

            //children for 33% layout here

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: the problem is that I do not need the top LinearLayout: (

Comment: using the value "invisible" in the upper layout, can work. thanks ;)

Comment: @MiguelC I hope that my solution will be useful for you.

Answer (score 5):

Since Aug 2015, you can perform this kind of layouts with native layouts, [PercentFrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) and [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html). Both are available in Android Support Library from revision 23.